# how to implement sliding window in magneto 2 admin

Tags: user-interface, magento2, sliding-window

magento 2 admin backend has one user interface that when we click on widnow new sliding window comes from right side.for sample view go to

**product->catalog->add product->image and videos tab-> and click addVideo button**

[image]

how to implement this sliding effect in our custom module.if anybody know please help with this.very important to me.

Answer (score 1):

That is implemented by using modal, you can use custom html in your admin form. here is normal example for basic html implementation:

```css
.modal.left .modal-dialog,
 .modal.right .modal-dialog {
  position: fixed;
  margin: auto;
  width: 320px;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
      -ms-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
       -o-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
 }

 .modal.left .modal-content,
 .modal.right .modal-content {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
 }
 
 .modal.left .modal-body,
 .modal.right .modal-body {
  padding: 15px 15px 80px;
 }

/*Left*/
 .modal.left.fade .modal-dialog{
  left: -320px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
     -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
       -o-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
          transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
 }
 
 .modal.left.fade.in .modal-dialog{
  left: 0;
 }
        
/*Right*/
 .modal.right.fade .modal-dialog {
  right: -320px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
     -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
       -o-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
          transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
 }
 
 .modal.right.fade.in .modal-dialog {
  right: 0;
 }

/* ----- MODAL STYLE ----- */
 .modal-content {
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
 }

 .modal-header {
  border-bottom-color: #EEEEEE;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
 }

/* ----- v CAN BE DELETED v ----- */
body {
 background-color: #78909C;
}

.demo {
 padding-top: 60px;
 padding-bottom: 110px;
}

.btn-demo {
 margin: 15px;
 padding: 10px 15px;
 border-radius: 0;
 font-size: 16px;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.btn-demo:focus {
 outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container demo">
 <div class="text-center">

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-demo" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">
   Click Here
  </button>
 </div>
 
 <!-- Modal -->
 <div class="modal right fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel2">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="modal-header">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
     <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel2">Right Sidebar</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
     <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
     </p>
    </div>

   </div><!-- modal-content -->
  </div><!-- modal-dialog -->
 </div><!-- modal -->
 
</div><!-- container -->
```

Comment: it is not a good solution. you could use magento sliding panel widget